# How to draw Java 3D Sliced Shape or cut piece

Tags: java, 3d

I want to slice a sphere or cone or any other shape in JAVA 3D.

ie. to cut it from center or from any other side

Comment: Do you want to implement this yourself? Are you looking for a library which might support this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `coneBody` method in [this class source code](http://docs.simtechnologies.de/df/d66/_quadrics_8java_source.html). Copy it out (preserving license at the top of the file..) and modify the loop so that it stops earlier than normal. This will crease a gap.

Use it like so:

```
gbuf = q.coneBody(-(double) (height / 2.0), (double) (height / 2.0 - height / ydivisions), (double) radius, (double) (radius / ydivisions), xdivisions, ydivisions - 1, 1.0 / (double) ydivisions, outside, texCoordYUp);
GeometryArray ga = gbuf.getGeom(flags);
```

This is how you use a GeometryArray: http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/java3d/how-to-use-geometryarray-for-by-reference.html (something like that, anyway)